# how to create a oauth client id for gcp programmatically

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

I can create OAuth2.0 Client IDs and Client Secret with Authorized redirect URIs using the GUI in GCP.. The Console URL is given below for reference

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

How do we do this in cloud shell or with the GCloud SDK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that no API from Google can manage OAuth client ID or Credentials related configuration.

I've not found any on API Library and many other questions related to this give the same answer ([can't manage API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45440274/565515) Key for example).

If you're a Terraform user, they're an open issue on Google Provider: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1287

Comment: I've opened a feature request on Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116182848

Comment: update: there's something coming on terraform-provider-google 3.15 ;)

Answer (score 3):

As of `terraform-provider-google` version 3.15, you can do this using the `google_iap_client` resource:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/iap_client

```
resource "google_iap_brand" "project_brand" {
  support_email     = "support@example.com"
  application_title = "Cloud IAP protected Application"
  project           = google_project_service.project_service.project
}

resource "google_iap_client" "project_client" {
  display_name = "Test Client"
  brand        =  google_iap_brand.project_brand.name
}
```

Comment: `google_iap_client ` does not expose all the attributes like "redirect uris" so if your client requires that, this operation is still manual.

Comment: Another important detail is that this is apparently only for INTERNAL use clients and not external use.