# GCP -- APIs & Services : Create OAuth client ID credentials programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I know how to create OAuth credentials via the GCP console (web interface).  I would like to know if anybody has found a way to do so programmatically, i.e. via an API call, a `gcloud` command, or some other way.

I suspect it may not be possible but I am trying to leave no stone unturned before I give in.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549109/how-to-create-a-oauth-client-id-for-gcp-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API or gcloud support, unfortunately.