# How to create Dialogflow agents automatically via REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to build a Bot-as-a-Service platform and I will be using Dialogflow for NLP. One key thing that is giving me headaches is the possibility to create a new Dialogflow agent whenever a user signs up to my service (and therefore configure their FAQs, etc...). From my research I know that each agent is associated with one project, so I must create a project first, but here's the big thing: To create a project I need to authenticate accordingly to Google Cloud Authentication and therefore supply my credentials in case of OAuth2  (I don't want my user's to log in with my user account) and it's not possible to programmatically create API keys for new projects [link here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425773/is-it-possible-to-create-google-api-key-programmatically&ved=2ahUKEwjVjIzt38PlAhUQ8BoKHQhgBUYQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1lhl_Fd15Js8WCQf6XQYiI)